# Pandas left join replacing columns values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to do a left join with two pandas dataframes: d1 and d2. However after the join, I want one column values to replace the NULL values in another column. Here's my datasets:

```
 vehicle_type     vehicle_id       sales       margin   
           a            11         200          0.1
           b            22         150          0.2      
           c           NaN        NaN         NaN      
           d           NaN        NaN         NaN          

vehicle_type     vehicle_id       sales       alignment        
           c           33        210             x      
           d           44        300             y
```

I would like the final result to be like the following, where the left join would replace the Null vehicle IDs and sales in D1:

```
 vehicle_type     vehicle_id       sales       margin     alignment  
           a            11         200          0.1         NaN
           b            22         150          0.2         NaN
           c            33         210          NaN         x
           d            44         300          NaN         y
```

I'm using the following code, but it is not working:

```
D3 = D1.merge(D2, on='vehicle_type',how='left')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) for correct align DataFrame by `vehicle_type` columns:

```
df3 = (df1.set_index('vehicle_type')
          .combine_first(df2.set_index('vehicle_type'))
          .reset_index())
print (df3)
  vehicle_type alignment  margin  sales  vehicle_id
0            a       NaN     0.1  200.0        11.0
1            b       NaN     0.2  150.0        22.0
2            c         x     NaN  210.0        33.0
3            d         y     NaN  300.0        44.0
```

Comment: This is great! Thank You!

Comment: if I have other columns in D1 and D2 which are not common, will they still remain there after the join? I want to keep them all, even if they are not common

Comment: Can you change data in question, but in text format for possible copy it? [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: I'll do that. I couldn;t find a way to make tables in stackoverflow. It was super manual and the editing was wierd. So i posted pictures

Comment: @HamzaKhalid - Ty add 4 spaces before, I can help you if copy some text.

Comment: Done : ) changed the table

Comment: @HamzaKhalid - First table was edited, can you edit another ones by this format?

Comment: have done that : ) thanks for the help btw. I know now how to make tables in questions

Comment: @HamzaKhalid - there are `NaN`s? or `null` strings? If NaNs for me working nice, edited answer.

Comment: Yes these are NaNs